# Adding a Tickbox Before PayPal Button

Tags: paypal

I use the following code to add a tickbox to agree to T&Cs before taking PayPal payment. The code works well but not if there are more than one tickboxes on the same page, in which case it wants the first tickbox ticked before proceeding.

How do I amend the code so that it functions with more than one tickbox on a page, please?

```html
    <script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    function confSubmit() {
      if(!document.getElementById("accept").checked) {
        alert("Please read and accept the Terms and Conditions in order to continue.");
        return false;
      }
    } // ]]></script>
    
    
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit();">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LAT8US8737YM66">
    
    <p><input id="accept" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    
    
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit();">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LAT8US8737YM66">
    
    <p><input id="accept" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    
    
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit();">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LAT8US8737YM66">
    
    <p><input id="accept" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML `id` values should be unique, never used on more than one element. Use a class if something is to be shared by more than one.

To make your JS look for the current form's checkbox, pass the event caller to your confSubmit function using `this`, and use `querySelector` to search within that for the class you want (identified with a period, `.accept`), since it's a class.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    function confSubmit(form) {
      if(!form.querySelector(".accept").checked) {
        alert("Please read and accept the Terms and Conditions in order to continue.");
        return false;
      }
    } // ]]></script>
    
    
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit(this);">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LAT8US8737YM66">
    
    <p><input class="accept" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    
    
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit(this);">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LAT8US8737YM66">
    
    <p><input class="accept" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    
    
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit(this);">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LAT8US8737YM66">
    
    <p><input class="accept" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```